# Picking Supervisors for a battery with correct Hysteresis

Tags: batteries, hysteresis

I am trying to find a Supervisors ic that will detect low voltage(5V) on 6v lead acid battery so I can disconnect the battery from the circuit using MOSFET or load driver.

how do you calculate hysteresis, since battery voltage will fluctuate when you disconnect the battery? (there is small pump 150ma max and circuit which use 50ma)

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76200.pdf

Comment: I have take look at this chip before but I never understand where you suppose to connect the charging power supply, since pack will connect the load and the battery will connect to battery pin.

Comment: Imagine that source battery on left is charging pack on right with control and cell sensors for control but your situation may be different